# OAuth 2 with spring 4, Authorisation Code Flow: access token request: POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, oauth-2.0, authorization

i used the example with sparklr2 and tonr2 from the tutorial http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/tutorial.html to have the OAuth 2 Provider. 
The sparklr2 is a server, that has realized OAuth 2 flows. The sparklr2 has the resources - the photogalery. 
The user will access via tonr2 on the photogalery of sparklr2.

If i call not modificated sparklr2 (sever) and the tonr2 (client) i have the following flows:

I login in in tonr2 with tonr2's user, then click on "View my Sparklr photos ".
Then i login in sparklr2 with sparklr2's user.
Then will be occurred the authorisation site, i allow for scope.read and scope.write.
Then i can see the photos.

Now i will use the Authorisation Code Flow in other client application as tonr2. Following steps are successful:
Login with sparklr2's user. ( The uri with /login will be send as GET)

Display of the authorisation site after login ( the /oauh/authorize with given client_id and given redirect_uri  and response_type=code&scope=read+write)

I have troubles, if i use the authorisation code from paramater given by redirect_url - 
if i try to request access token via POST with curl :

"curl -X POST http://geodez.com/oauth/token     -F client_id=tonr  -F client_secret=mysecret  -F code=1IfhzU"

The following error will be returned:
"{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}"

I look at loggin by sparklr2 and found the following:

"POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET"

I don't know, how to allow that. I tried to modify the config classes, but it is failed:

My modificated config classes:

OAuth 2, Authorisation Code Flow: access token request: POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /**
POST /oauth/token' doesn't match 'GET /**

==================

```
org.myt.springframework.config.MethodSecurityConfig

/*
 * Copyright 2002-2013 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.myt.springframework.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

/**
 * @author Rob Winch
 * @author Dave Syer
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityConfiguration securityConfig;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}


===============
org.myt.springframework.config.OAuth2ServerConfig
===============

/*
 * Copyright 2002-2013 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.myt.springframework.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.UserApprovalHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;

import org.myt.oauth.service.oauth.ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler;

/**
 * @author Rob Winch
 * 
 */
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String OAUTH_RESOURCE_ID = "GradleOAuth21";

    @Configuration
    @Order(10)
    protected static class UiResourceConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/sync/**","/me", "/oauth/token")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sync/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/me").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/photos").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/photos/trusted/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/photos/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/photos/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')");
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(OAUTH_RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/sync/**", "/oauth/users/**", "/oauth/clients/**","/me", "/oauth/token")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/oauth/token").permitAll()
                    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/token").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/sync").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .antMatchers("/sync/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .antMatchers("/photos/trusted/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('trust')")
                    .antMatchers("/photos/user/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('trust')")
                    .antMatchers("/photos/**").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*")
                        .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')")
                    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/clients/([^/].*?)/users/.*")
                        .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')")
                    .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/clients/.*")
                        .access("#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

            // @formatter:off

            clients.inMemory().withClient("tonr")
                        .resourceIds(OAUTH_RESOURCE_ID)
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                        .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .secret("mysecret");
  /**          .and()
                    .withClient("my-less-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")

    **/     // @formatter:on
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.realm("client");
        }

    }

    protected static class Stuff {

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Bean
        public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
            TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
            store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            return store;
        }

        @Bean
        @Lazy
        @Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
        public ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler() throws Exception {
            ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler();
            handler.setApprovalStore(approvalStore());
            handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
            handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            handler.setUseApprovalStore(true);
            return handler;
        }
    }

}
=============
org.myt.springframework.config.SecurityConfiguration
=============
package org.myt.springframework.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //TODO Change it after user story test. See also login.jsp
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user1@demo.com").password("user2").roles("USER").and().withUser("user2@demo.com")
                .password("user2").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/images/**", "/oauth/uncache_approvals", "/oauth/cache_approvals");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
                 http.authorizeRequests().regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/oauth/token").permitAll()
                         .antMatchers("/sync/**").permitAll()
                         .anyRequest().authenticated()
                         .and()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/login.jsp?authorization_error=true")
                .and()
            // TODO: put CSRF protection back into this endpoint
            .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize")).disable()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.jsp")
                .logoutUrl("/logout.do")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("j_username")
                    .passwordParameter("j_password")
                    .failureUrl("/login.jsp?authentication_error=true")
                   .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do");// Seems to be related the default MVC controller
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
=======

org.myt.springframework.config.ServletInitializer
=======
/*
 * Copyright 2013-2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License is distributed on
 * an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package org.myt.springframework.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 * @author Dave Syer
 * 
 */
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(getClass()));
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filter.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
======
org.myt.springframework.config.WebMvcConfig
======
package org.myt.springframework.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.ClientDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.ApprovalStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;

import org.myt.oauth.service.PhotoInfo;
import org.myt.oauth.service.PhotoService;
import org.myt.oauth.service.impl.PhotoServiceImpl;
import org.myt.oauth.service.mvc.AccessConfirmationController;
import org.myt.oauth.service.mvc.AdminController;
import org.myt.oauth.service.mvc.PhotoController;
import org.myt.oauth.service.mvc.PhotoServiceUserController;
import org.myt.oauth.service.oauth.ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

   @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() throws Exception {
        ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
        contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        MappingJackson2JsonView defaultView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        defaultView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
        contentViewResolver.setViewResolvers(Arrays.<ViewResolver>asList(viewResolver));
        contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View>asList(defaultView));
        return contentViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoServiceUserController photoServiceUserController(PhotoService photoService) {
       PhotoServiceUserController photoServiceUserController = new PhotoServiceUserController();
       return photoServiceUserController;
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoController photoController(PhotoService photoService) {
        PhotoController photoController = new PhotoController();
        photoController.setPhotoService(photoService);
        return photoController;
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessConfirmationController accessConfirmationController(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService, ApprovalStore approvalStore) {
        AccessConfirmationController accessConfirmationController = new AccessConfirmationController();
        accessConfirmationController.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        accessConfirmationController.setApprovalStore(approvalStore);
        return accessConfirmationController;
    }

    @Bean
    public PhotoServiceImpl photoServices() {
        List<PhotoInfo> photos = new ArrayList<PhotoInfo>();
        photos.add(createPhoto("1", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("2", "paul"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("3", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("4", "paul"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("5", "marissa"));
        photos.add(createPhoto("6", "paul"));

        PhotoServiceImpl photoServices = new PhotoServiceImpl();
        photoServices.setPhotos(photos);
        return photoServices;
    }


    @Bean
    public AdminController adminController(TokenStore tokenStore, ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices,
            ExtendedApprovalStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler) {
        AdminController adminController = new AdminController();
        adminController.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        adminController.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        adminController.setUserApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler);
        return adminController;
    }

   private PhotoInfo createPhoto(String id, String userId) {
        PhotoInfo photo = new PhotoInfo();
        photo.setId(id);
        photo.setName("photo" + id + ".jpg");
        photo.setUserId(userId);
        photo.setResourceURL("/impl/resources/" + photo.getName());
        return photo;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
=====
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to use basic authentication for making the request to get the access code. Use client id as the user name, and the client secret as the password.

Comment: what with Single Page Applications where u cannot store passes?